# Is there going to be an update for the timezone file for Turkey, since the daylight saving timezone GMT+3 will be the permanent timezone from now on?

Tags: timezone, dst, turkish

The Turkish government decided to stay at the EEST (GMT+3) timezone (daylight saving timezone) from now on; the timezone will be fixed to GMT+3 from now on in Turkey. Is there going to be an update for the timezone file for Linux systems due to this change? When is it going to be published?

Comment: This is OT for StackOverflow, but you should know that the 2016g file contains this change.  The proper place to ask/watch is on the TZ discussion list here: http://www.iana.org/time-zones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it has been decided to stay in current timezone, you can use GMT+3 until getting any update from Turkish officials.

```
sudo unlink /etc/localtime 
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT+3 /etc/localtime
```

Good luck!

Comment: This won't properly reflect the time zone offset of past date/time values.

Comment: Explain a lil bit more please.

Comment: If you just set it to +3, applications that depend on time zones will think that the local time zone offset has *always* been +3.  This is incorrect, because the time zone offset used to alternate between +3 and +2. The time zone should be set to `Europe/Istanbul`, with the 2016g update applied, so the history of changes is correct. Read the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially "Time Zone != Offset".

Comment: Turkish timezone gonna be only +3 when you compare it with 0 zone, England. It has decided to not switch to +2 anymore, it is still.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  It did in the past.  If I have a timestamp recorded in data from January 2016 (for example), at the offset for that period is +2.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for vmware no need to play on it , its default UTC

Related article

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2135594

Comment: The related article that you mentioned is discussing an earlier situation (happened in 2015); not the one that I arise (happened in 2016).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use +3 because zones like Etc/GMT+6 are intentionally reversed for backwards compatibility with POSIX standards.

Instead of +3 use below;

```
sudo unlink /etc/localtime 
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT-3 /etc/localtime
```

Otherwise you will have the reversed and will have 6 hours difference.